# Как в Python получить имя активного файла

Tags: python, windows, winapi

Может кто-нибудь подскажет в сторону какого модуля посмотреть?

Задача — получить имя файла, окно которого активно. Как учесть, что, например, новый документ Word может быть открыт, но еще не иметь имени. Возможно, создается временное имя.

Также если файл кем-то переименовывался, нужно записывать как менялись имена файлов, чтобы отследить первоначальное имя.

Описание:

Пользователь открывает, создает, сворачивает, закрывает файлы `example1.doc`, `example2.doc`, `example.xls`. Нужно записывать продолжительность работы с каждым документом когда он активен, не свернут с записью названия файла

Comment: А на входе у вас что? Идентификатор окна в виде числа? GUID?

Comment: А операционная система какая?

Comment: Ну насколько я понимаю алгоритм примерно такой: запускаемся в автостарте демоном, подписываемся на все события всех окон, не уверен, что без прав администратора такое возможно, на каждый чих получаем нотификацию, в которой уже видим ID окошка и события. Дальше уже просто ваша логика поверх.